# Realm integration with Laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, realm, real-time

I'm working on a project which requires a real-time sync database feature. To achieve this task we are using [Realm.io (Cloud Database)](https://realm.io/) which supports native SDKs for iOS, Android, React-Native, .Net and Node. The problem we are facing is that the admin portal is developed on PHP-Server-Side (Laravel 5.3 Framework). There is any way around to interact the Cloud Database in PHP or Javascript (Laravel Vue.Js).

Right now I've setup a server on Node.js + Socket.IO on linux server, and it broadcast the changes + Authentication + Signup by making api using (express.js).

Its actually time taking process, Like

```
clinet (Socket)->server->(realm(node)) (Socket)->client
```

So I want to reduce this process and interact directly with Realm.Io Instance

Please share any example build on PHP or Client Side Javascript to easily integrate with Realm.IO (Cloud Database).

Comment: Realm doesn't have a PHP SDK at the moment. Moreover, Realm JavaScript only supports node.js and React Native.